# How to use @SequenceGenerator annotation through eclipselink to get the sequence next/last value from Maria db database sequence object

Tags: java, mariadb, eclipselink, database-migration, mariadb-10.5

The below code for Java works fine in Oracle-eclipselink-java, as we migrated the same to mariadb, we are facing the issue stated below.

### Db sequence:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE `com_seq` start with 370700 minvalue 1 maxvalue
9223372036854775806 increment by 1 cache 20 nocycle ENGINE=InnoDB
```

### Java code/Entity class:

```java
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "com_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "com_test_sample ", sequenceName = "com_seq", allocationSize=1)

private Integer id;
```

Note: `Strategy = sequence` or `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` (tried with both).

When we try with above coding and it's defined values we are getting below error:

```
Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO com_test_sample (ACTION, COMPLAINT_ID, TEXT_PARAMS, CREATE_TIMESTAMP, DELETE_REMARK, OVV_STATUS, PREV_OVV_STATUS, REMARK, VALUE, PERSON_ID, SUB_PERSON_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [DRAFT_STATUS_SET, 370703, null, 2022-10-11 19:37:38.22, null, DRAFT, null, null, null, 25071, 25071]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(de.wirthedv.OVV.complaintjournal.domain.ComplaintJournal@1f)
```

Comment: What is the database platform EclipseLink is using? If you don't know, turn on logging to fine/finest and it should show when it deploys/logs in. This level of logging might also show what it determines is set on your entity and why it isn't trying to pre-allocate a value from your sequence; first guess though is that you are not using the MariaDBPlatform and instead using a MySQLPlatform. Maria's main difference (I've been told) is it supports sequences while MySQL only had identity, which might explain there not being an attempt to read a sequence value.

Comment: You can specify the platform using the target-database persistence property (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm ) and specify MariaDB , though I'm not sure what version it was added in.

Comment: GeneratedValue.generator should refer to sequence generator(!) name! (So `com_test_sample` in your case)

Comment: Chris, we are using <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Mysql"/> do u suggest to use mariadb instead of mysql ?

Comment: @ xerx593, yes I have tried using the same generator name. 
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "com_test_sample ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "com_test_sample ", sequenceName = "com_seq", allocationSize=1)

Comment: Today I have tested with GenerationType.SEQUENCE, GenerationType.AUTO, GenerationType.Table, GenerationType.Identity.
For,
GenerationType.SEQUENCE  -- field id does not have a default value.

Comment: Includes seqeuncegenerator line as below

@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "com_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "com_test_sample ", sequenceName = "com_seq", allocationSize=1)
---------------------

For GenerationType.Auto, GenerationType.table -- commented sequencegenerator line as below

@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "com_seq")
#@SequenceGenerator(name = "com_test_sample ", sequenceName = "com_seq", allocationSize=1)

Comment: received error as 

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=4344) Table 'dbname.sequence' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
        bind => [50, SEQ_GEN_TABLE]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_TABLE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
javax.faces.FacesException: #{complaintEditView.createComplaint()}: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseExceptio

Comment: As we got Table 'dbname.sequence' doesn't exist  error: we created the table and started the server. but received the below mentioned error.

CREATE TABLE ddname.`SEQUENCE` (
 SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50),
 SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(38,0),
 CONSTRAINT PK_SEQUENCE PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME),
 CONSTRAINT SYS_C0087791 CHECK ("SEQ_NAME" IS NOT NULL)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_SEQUENCE ON A4PCCT.`SEQUENCE` (SEQ_NAME);

Comment: WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{complaintEditView.createComplaint()}: Exception [EclipseLink-4011] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table information is not complete.

Comment: javax.faces.FacesException: #{complaintEditView.createComplaint()}: Exception [EclipseLink-4011] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table information is not complete.

Comment: We would like to know, whether eclipse link supports for maria db 10.5 RDS (aws) in the perspective of generating a sequence through database sequence object ?